# Way to create multiple indexed void dataframes from a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know I can use `data = pd.DataFrame()` in order to create a void dataframe.

Is there a way to use a loop to create multiple void dataframes indexed by the iteration of the loop ? Something like:

```
for i in range (1, k):
    data_i = pd.DataFrame()
```

Of course, in this kind of writing, the index `i` is not taken as a variable... What kind of writing should be used in order to have the index `i` properly incremented from 1 to k ?

I've been looking for it for a while but I can't remember. Something using `data_i.format(i)`, no; `f'data_{i}'`, no; `data_{i}.format(i)`, no. Something obvious I am missing.

Comment: perhaps use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Like enke suggested, using a dictionary would be a good idea.

```
data = {}
for i in range (1, k):
    # DataFrame names as integer "i"
    data[i] = pd.DataFrame()
    # DataFrame names as string "str_i"
    data["str_" + str(i)] = pd.DataFrame()
```

You can then loop through the DataFrames to populate them, if this is what you wanted to do:

```
for i in data.keys():
    data[i]["col1"] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Else to access an individual DataFrame in the dictionary:

```
data[i]
```